# WordPress Code Access to Restricted Content without Registration

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization

Ok this is completely past my knowledge but I need to have this function and wondering if anyone can help or know of a plugin that can do this job..

1. I have content on my WordPress site that I want to restrict by a time frame, say 7 days.
2. A user needs to enter a code to access the restricted content.
3. When a user enters the code, the timer for the restricted content starts and expires 7 days from when they first entered the code.
4. The user does not need to register to the WordPress site. Access is to restricted content is provided through simply entering the code.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different plugins that can serve your purpose:

[Content Control – User Access Restriction Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-control/): It allows you to restrict access to specific posts to both logged in and logged out users.

[Restriction Timeouts](https://restrictcontentpro.com/downloads/restriction-timeouts/?ref=19): It enables you to specify a date and time when restricted post will have its restrictions removed.

However, I don't think that there is a single plugin that can serve all of your purposes.